# How to look for a pattern in data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like:

```
   ID                Time Event
 1: 1 2016-09-25 14:47:52     1
 2: 1 2016-10-03 19:35:04     1
 3: 1 2016-10-03 21:11:00    -1
 4: 1 2016-10-04 14:25:56     1
 5: 1 2016-11-05 01:40:13     1
 6: 1 2016-11-27 04:40:21     1
 7: 1 2016-12-04 02:36:37     1
 8: 1 2017-01-12 13:48:01     1
 9: 1 2017-01-15 03:32:35     1
10: 1 2017-02-05 01:35:07     1
11: 1 2017-02-05 02:29:31     1
12: 1 2017-02-05 02:34:33     1
13: 2 2016-07-15 08:14:11     1
14: 2 2016-07-22 22:15:44     1
15: 2 2016-07-23 12:00:00    -1
16: 2 2016-11-30 18:21:51     1
17: 2 2016-12-03 07:00:31     1
18: 2 2016-12-06 06:30:34     1
19: 2 2016-12-16 10:00:50     1
20: 2 2017-01-16 08:33:16     1
```

and I am trying to check if positive events occurred after a negative one grouped by ID. My ideal output is a data.table with:

```
ID Outcome
1    TRUE
2    TRUE
```

I don't know how to formulate the filtering condition that should take into consideration the Time column and the Event column: I want to know if, for a given ID, there are Event = 1 with Time > Time at Event -1... But I am not able to formulate this in code... Anyone can help?

I attach here a demo dataset:

```
fakedata <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                   1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
                   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                   2L, 2L), Time = c("2016-09-25 14:47:52", "2016-10-03 19:35:04", 
                                                       "2016-10-03 21:11:00", "2016-10-04 14:25:56", "2016-11-05 01:40:13", 
                                                       "2016-11-27 04:40:21", "2016-12-04 02:36:37", "2017-01-12 13:48:01", 
                                                       "2017-01-15 03:32:35", "2017-02-05 01:35:07", "2017-02-05 02:29:31", 
                                                       "2017-02-05 02:34:33", "2016-07-15 08:14:11", "2016-07-22 22:15:44", 
                                                       "2016-07-23 12:00:00", "2016-11-30 18:21:51", "2016-12-03 07:00:31", 
                                                       "2016-12-06 06:30:34", "2016-12-16 10:00:50", "2017-01-16 08:33:16"
                   ), Event = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 
                                1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("ID", "Time", "Event"), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                            "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

Comment: `sapply(split(fakedata,fakedata$ID), function(x) is.na(which(diff(x$Event) == 2)) == FALSE)`

Comment: thanks, I see it works but it does not look like a proper data.table solution

Comment: Could do `fakedata[order(as.POSIXct(Time)), any(Event - shift(Event, fill = 0) == 2), keyby = ID]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `data.table` method using base R functions `any` and `which` along with the `&&` operator.

```
fakedata[order(ID, as.POSIXct(Time)),
         .(outcome=any(Event == -1) && Event[which(Event == -1)+1] > 0), by=ID]
   ID outcome
1:  1    TRUE
2:  2    TRUE
```

As david-arenburg mentioned in the comments, if is a good idea to make sure that the data set is ordered properly prior to computing. For `data.table`, we can do this in the i argument. Following david-arenburg's  comment, I ordered it on ID and then on `as.POSIXct(Time)`.

In the j argument, `.(outcome=any(Event==-1) && Event[which(Event == -1)+1] > 0)`, `any(Event == -1)` checks if -1 is ever present, if yes, then `Event[which(Event == -1)+1] > 0)` checks if in each of the instances where -1 is present, the immediately following value of Event is positive. If the first instance fails, then a FALSE is returned.

Comment: You need to make sure the `Time` column is in order too I would guess.

Comment: Good call. I'll add that.

Comment: my data.table is ordered like fakedata[order(ID,Time)]

Comment: Apologies, but I don't understand the Event[which(Event==1)+1] > 0) condition... does it checks that the Event value with Time>Time at -1 is positive?

Comment: I fixed a typo and added some more commentary. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: I still don't get it, sorry. What does it mean: "the immediately value of Event is positive"? Besides, I tried to run your code and I get a lot of NAs, what does that mean?

Comment: ok I think I see it now, you take the Event at position which(Event==-1)+1

Comment: Should read "immediately following value of Event." This is found by indexing with `which(Event == -1)+1`. Two ways I can think of that you would get NAs: 1, you have NAs in your Event variable; 2, a -1 occurs as the final observation for some ID.